# Find first match in table range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this working formula that I'd like to expand for more flexibility:

```
=SUMIF(MyTable[Date],"="&$D5,MyTable[Account Balance])
```

Occasionally, `D5` will not have a match in `MyTable[Date]` range. I'd like it to do `"="&$D5+1` and then +1... and so on until first match in the range is located.

Comment: Is it too much to hope for that the dates are either in ascending or descending order (albeit with gaps)?

Comment: You could run a `"="&IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D5,MyTable[Account Balance]),D5),D6)` but for doing this dynamically... hmm... I have to think this over...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next date can be easily located on a sorted or unsorted range of dates using a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) to rank and passing that result into a [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) as the *k* parameter.

In the following, I've used [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) syntax to provide more universality than [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) (e.g. the parameters are necessarily reversed).

The standard formula in G5 is,

```
=SUMIFS(MyTable[account balance], MyTable[date], LARGE(MyTable[date], COUNTIF(MyTable[date], ">="&F5)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: sumifs_next_date]

If you have blanks in the [Account Balance] column that need to be discarded, the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) will have to become a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) and the [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) will have to become an [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF). In G5 above as,

```
=SUMIFS(MyTable[account balance], MyTable[date], AGGREGATE(14, 6, MyTable[date]/(MyTable[account balance]<>""), COUNTIFS(MyTable[date], ">="&F5, MyTable[account balance], "<>")))
```

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: If the `MyTable[account balance]` range occasionally has blanks they get picked up as first available value, 0. I tried to patch with this but no go: `=SUMIFS(MyTable[account balance], MyTable[Date], LARGE(MyTable[Date], COUNTIFS(MyTable[Date], ">="&$C4, MyTable[account balance], "<>0")))` ...any help?