# Find last match in table range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My original question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528984/find-first-match-in-table-range/34529446#34529446). I've been trying to build on top of that to create a mirror action to what the original issue tried to resolve:

```
=SUMIFS( MyTable[Ending Account Balance], MyTable[Date], AGGREGATE( 15, 6, MyTable[Date] / ( MyTable[Ending Account Balance] <>"" ), COUNTIFS( MyTable[Date], "<="&D2, MyTable[Date], ">="&C2, MyTable[Ending Account Balance], "<>" ) ) )
```

I'd like to find first available Date value but counting UP from last given. The above works in its logic but always picks SECOND from last instead of the very last (`D2`) as I need it to. The reason for `">="&C2` is that, without it, I ran into the problem of when this formula is copied down the range it fills according to future dates but I need this to only apply to current time span.

Jan 8 balance of 222.00 is what I need to get in `E2`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [AGGREGATE¹](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) function's [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) sub-function (**15**); it seems to me that you should be using the [LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) sub-function (**14**).

In E2 as,

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(MyTable[ending account balance],  "<>0", MyTable[date], ">="&C2, MyTable[date], "<="&D2),
    SUMIFS( MyTable[ending account balance], MyTable[date],
        AGGREGATE(14, 6, MyTable[date]/((MyTable[ending account balance] <>"")*(MyTable[date]>=C2)*(MyTable[date]<=D2)), 1))
   , "")
```

Filled down to E3 will result in a blank cell due to the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) check.

[image: account_balance_aggregate_large]

[image: account_balance_aggregate_large_2]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: I like to think I make them dance.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=SUM(MyTable[Ending Account Balance] * (MyTable[Date]=MAX(MyTable[Date])))
```

entered as an array formula (`CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`).

**Edit:**

To have it match only within a range (C2 to D2 say):

```
=SUM(MyTable[Ending Account Balance] * (MyTable[Date]=MAX(MyTable[Date] *
  (MyTable[Date]>=C2) * (MyTable[Date]<=D2) )))
```

Comment: This works but does not solve my original problem because when I copy this down to `e3` I still get 222.00 there and that should be blank (waiting for its corresponding values from the 1/10 - 1/15 range when those become available in MyTable)

Comment: Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: Did you use 'ctrl shift enter'?